Determinant of a Vandermonde-like matrix with non-consequent powers
I need to calculate the determinant of a matrix which is built like a Vandermonde matrix, but has arbitrary increasing powers instead of consequent ones like
$$
[M] =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^{n_1} & x_2^{n_1} & \cdots & x_K^{n_1}\\
x_1^{n_2} & x_2^{n_2} & \cdots & x_K^{n_2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_1^{n_K} & x_2^{n_K} & \cdots & x_K^{n_K}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $n_1 < n_2< \dots < n_K$, $n_i \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$.
Is it possible to represent the determinant of $[M]$ in some general elegant form, or is this just a case of each such matrix having a unique determinant expression?
